# Video for Windows error 80044066

Tags: winapi, avi, vfw

I'm using Video for Windows to record screen grabs to AVI files. Usually it works fine, but some users report the error:

AVI error (80044066): Bad format

Any explanations of what this error means and what might be causing it would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that some machines have the right codec installed but others do not?